# Access 2019 with SQL Server 2017 - Macro ApplyFilter limitation and Very slow when using sub query (Is Access processing locally?)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Two related questions. I hope that's OK. If not, please feel free to focus on the second question!

I have an Access 2019 database form that uses a macro for search functionality. The form recordsource is based on two tables using a left join. Any macro options that use ApplyFilter based on any fields in the joined tables operate correctly and quickly.

However, I need a search to use a subquery and for some reason the Macro Where Condition does not support a sub query (it shows a red exclamation point and gives an error when trying to save the macro "The 'ApplyFilter' macro action has an invalid value for the 'Where Condition' argument").
The Where Condition is:

`JobPropertyID in (select PropertyID from Properties where PropertyAddress like '*' & [Address contains] & '*')`

(I have tried various combinations of % and * wildcards, and quotes).
This used to work in earlier versions of Access (we upgraded from 2003 to 2019).

**So, question 1 is - Is this a known limitation?**
(I can work-around it by using RunCode to set the Filter and FilterOn in VBA code).

**The second, and more important question** relates to the performance when using a sub query. For example, this pseudo query to return jobs at matching property addresses:

`select JobID, JobDescription, CompanyName from JobDetails Left Join Company on JobCompanyID = CompanyID where JobPropertyID in (select PropertyID from Properties where PropertyAddress like '*High Street*')`

This does work but can take about a minute to run in Access. If I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio it shows the results in less than a second. I looked at the output in SQL Profiler and it appears that Access is requesting all rows from the joined tables and all rows from the Properties table (with no criteria being applied to either) and then, presumably, applying the filter and the sub query internally.

Is there a way to encourage Access to let SQL Server do the work?

I have tried using a pass through query, and this returns the correct results quickly, but is read only, so not suitable for a form that allows editing.

I suppose I could display the search results in subform and apply a filter to the main form from the OnCurrent event in the subform. But this seems a rather clunky solution.

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: Are you sure you need a subquery here? It sounds like you could simply do a INNER JOIN between JobDetails and Properties. The query should then run on the server. -- If not, please provide sample data.

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the suggestion. I did consider the inner join approach, and to emulate the results for a single sub query it would work well. However, the query could require up to 3 sub queries (depending on the user's search requirement) and joining to 3 more tables when 95% of the time they won't be required seems very inefficient. I could build the joins dynamically but am somewhat reluctant to change the RecordSource of the form as this is a legacy system I'm maintaining.

Answer (score 0):

Access tends to like `Exists` over `In` a lot when it comes to performance/translation, and that second query can be rewritten to an `Exists`:

```
select JobID, JobDescription, CompanyName from JobDetails 
Left Join Company on JobCompanyID = CompanyID 
where Exists(select 1 from Properties where PropertyAddress like '*High Street*' AND JobPropertyID  = PropertyID )
```

As for that filter, you can pass a filter string to avoid the macro from doing weird stuff:

```
="JobPropertyID in (select PropertyID from Properties where PropertyAddress like '*' & [Address contains] & '*')"
```

But you should really consider using VBA for your own sanity (working with macros is intended for beginners but quickly becomes harder than learning VBA even when doing trivial tasks), unless that's restricted in your company, in which case you will run into obstacles using Access.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Erik. I tried using the Exists method, but unfortunately the query still takes about a minute to run, and SQL Profiler shows that no criteria is being applied to the two queries that it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Any client side filter from Access? One table - works great.
A left join - usually ok!

but, after that ? The problem is that Access (and most) ODBC connections view EACH table as a 100% separate link. While your linked tables point to SQL server? They don't have to!
So, one table could point to say a local FoxPro/dbase table.
Another table could point to a linked Excel sheet.
And another table could point to sql server.

So, if you try and use any compilex sql - involving joins, or ESPECIALLY sub-quires, then Access really can't make the assuming that these additional tables are from the same server - and they might be Excel sheets!! - So, those data sources are "often" seen and assumed by access to be seperate tables. (and while Access is amazing that you can say do sub-queries against to linked Excel sheets? Well, there no server on the other end - Access client side has to figure this out to make it work.

You have two great choices to fix this issue.

the best choice? Build that query server side (in SSMS stuido). Save it as a view. Now the joins and all that jazz will occur 100% server side. You can STILL very effective filter against that "table" in Access. You of course now will have a linked "view" in access. But access sees this as one table - filters work fantastic in this case.

And in a lot of cases, that sub-query can be re-wrtten as a left join (not always - but often so). So again, build that complex join server side, save it as view, and then from Access link to that view.

You can filter against columns in both parent and child table - it again works well.

However, if you really need that sub query and worse so that sub query needs values/paramters from the child table?

Well, then build the query but use what is called a Pass-though query in Access. When you do this, the sql is sent raw un-touched to sql server (no difference in speed, and what you put in that PT query will work 100% exactly the same if you just typed that SQL right into SSMS. So, for example, that query that ran so fast?

Take it 100% "as-is", un-changed. Build a PT query in Access, and then cut+paste in that working and speedy query you had. It will now run the same in Access. Just keep in mind that a PT query in access is read only, but often with sub-query etc., such queries would be anyway.

The next last one? Well, with a PT query in Access, you can use those to call + use + consume a stored procedure. And stored procedures are often used because this lets you EASY set parameters in say a sub query (not that you ever really needed say t-sql code, and some big procedure to run - but you need paramaters - and a SQL stored procedures give you this ability.

in VBA, to execute that stored procedure? Well, I create a working PT query, (could be anything or any T-SQL). I then use that PT query over and over in code.

eg like this:

```
dim rstData      as DAO.RecordSet

With Currentdb.QueryDefs("MyPTQuery")
   .SQL = "EXEC dbo.GetInvoices"
   set rstData = .OpenRecordSet()
End if
```

Now above, the stored procedure (to get say invoices) did not have any parameters, but it can and could. So, say you have to pass the year, and month to get invoices.

So, your PT query could/would be used like this (from SSMS).

```
EXEC dbo.GetInvoices 2021, 3
```

So, you have to pass it the year + month. IN VBA, then we could go:

```
dim Mymonth    as integer
dim Myyear     as integer

MyMonth = Month(date)    ' get current month based on today date
Myyear  = Year(date)     ' get current year based on today date


With Currentdb.QueryDefs("MyPTQuery")
   .SQL = "EXEC dbo.GetInvoices " & MyYear & "," & MyMonth
   rst = .OpenRecordSet()
End if
```

And you not limited to shoving the results into a recordset.

Say, we have a report - set the source of the Report to "MyPTQquery"

Then do this:

```
With Currentdb.QueryDefs("MyPTQuery")
   .SQL = "EXEC dbo.GetInvoices " & MyYear & "," & MyMonth
End if

' now open report
docmd.OpenReport "rptInvoices",acViewePreview
```

So that query can be used for anything - reports, forms or a VBA recordset.

So I find that views are the most easy, perform REALLY good, and you can even have criteria against that view, and it works very well. (so this is the least amount of work). So built that messy multi-table join server side, save as view, and then link from Access client side. This works VERY well, since often  you can take a REALLY big dog pile query in Access with multi-table joins - it not going to work well.

So, you take that messy query, move it to SSMS - get it working. Then save that working SQL as a view. Now re-name (or delete) the query. Say it was

```
 QueryInvoices.
```

Well, now link to the view with the same name. now that VBA code, the forms, and the reports that were ALL using that messy client side query don't have to be changed!! - the name of the server side view is thus linked with that old query name. Again this gives fantastic performance.

So, the above should give you some ideas. As noted, views are your friend here. But as noted, the problem is you can't inject/have parameters in the sub query from Access being passed to a view. So, you can either build a stored procedure - use above PT Query idea.

And the other way? Well, you build the whole SQL string in VBA code, shove it into that PT query - and that also works. (but in-line messy long sql statements in VBA code can be quite a challenge. But for parameters in a sub-query, then the view trick can't be used, so you travel down the PT query road.